# How golang gets the detailed process of the request?

Tags: go, cookiejar

I use cookiejar to manage cookies, but I can't get the correct result.

How to know whether a request carries the cookie correctly?

```golang
jar, err := cookiejar.New(&cookiejar.Options{PublicSuffixList: publicsuffix.List})
client := &http.Client{
    Jar: jar,
}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://xxx", nil)
ParsedURL, _ := url.Parse("https://xxx")
fmt.Println("cookies1", client.Jar.Cookies(ParsedURL))
fmt.Println("cookies2",req.Cookies())
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
resp.Body.Close()
```

cookies1 is right

cookies2 is empty

So, can you see all the information like a browser's console?

Comment: "cookies2 is empty" of course it is empty. Why should `req` contain any cookies? req is a plain, naked HTTP request where you set up exactly two data points: the method GET and the URL https://xxx. "So, can you see all the information like a browser's console?" The browser console displays the user agents data which is something different than the servers data (like your req).

Comment: @Volker That's why I asked how to know the cookie in the request header, not the response header

Comment: If you use the `client` with the configured Jar the client will add the cookies to the request wen actually `Do` the request. I have to admit I do not really understand what you are asking. Try inspecting `req` after client.Do.